# Writing a certain amount of lines in a file C#

Tags: c#, file

I am currently writing a program that takes in a file, loops through all of the lines.
The file contains a lot of variables + values in this format:

> Message =
>
> "alfjawejf1ij4l2jr183fhaalfjawejf1ij4l2jr183fhahalfjawejf1ij4l2jr183fhahalfjawejf1ij4l2jr183fhahalfjawejf1ij4l2jr183fhahh" //the string will encompass multiple 
>    lines of length
>
> Answer = ?

My program will modify the value within message and write it in a new file.
How do I store multiple lines of the value into one string (so I can modify it)?
I need it so that it recognizes "message", starts storing the next few lines, detects "answer" and stops.

For the string holding the message value, I believe some sort of concatenation will be used (concatenating multiple lines).

```
string[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@path); //file is read
            string pathNew = Path.GetDirectoryName(path) + "\\completed_" + Path.GetFileName(path);

using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(@pathNew))
            {
                foreach (string line in file)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (line.Substring(0,6).Equals("Msg = "))
                        {
                            foreach (string msg in file)
                            {

                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Some additional examples would be helpful; are the “values” always on a separate line from the variables? Are they always strings? How do you represent a quote character inside a string? Can there be non-value text like what appears to be a comment in your example?

Comment: You can read all the text as a single string using `File.ReadAllText`, and then split it on `"Message ="` to get all the messages, and then split each message on `"Answer = "` to get the answer for each message (assuming the format is `"Message = some message Answer = some answer Message = some other message Answer = some other answer"`). It would be helpful if you included an actual sample from the file, since your code clearly was not written for the sample you've provided (there is no line where `line.Substring(0,6).Equals("Msg = ")` is `true`).

Comment: How do you define that it "stops"?

Answer (score 0):

You could create it pretty easily, if you would provide a method that returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, and then use the [`File.WriteAllLines( string, IEnumerable<string> )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_WriteAllLines_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) utility method

A way you could do it could be

```
private IEnumerable<string> ReturnAllMessages( IEnumerable<string> lines )
{
  bool isMessage = false;
  foreach (var line in lines)
  {
    if (line.StartsWith('Msg =')) 
    {
      isMessage = true;
      // set a flag that the next lines are part of the message
      // this would exclude the rest of the line from the results
      // if you want it, you could use:
      // yield return line.Substring('Msg ='.Length));
      continue;
    }
    if (line.StartsWith('Answer =')) 
    {
      // remove the flag
      isMessage = false;
      continue;
    } 
    if (isMessage) 
    {
      // yield a line that is a message
      yield return line;
    }
  }
}
```

and then use the method in the following way

```
File.WriteAllLines( @newPath, ReturnAllMessages( File.ReadAllLines( @path ) ) );
```

(didn't really test the code though, so just use it as a reference ;) )

Comment: @JavaNoob if it has helped you as answer, feel free marking it as such :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to read all the text as a single string using `File.ReadAllText`, and then split it on `"Message ="` to get all the messages, and then split each message on `"Answer = "` to get the answer for each message (assuming the format is `"Message = some message Answer = some answer Message = some other message Answer = some other answer"`).

It would be helpful if you included an actual sample from the file, since your code clearly was not written for the sample you've provided (there is no line where `line.Substring(0,6).Equals("Msg = ")` is `true`).

I've included a method in my sample below that creates a text file with a multi-line message, and then showed how you can read the message into a variable and display it in the console window.

Hope this helps:

```
private static void CreateFile(string filePath)
{
    if (File.Exists(filePath)) File.Delete(filePath);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));

    var fileLines = new List<string>
    {
        "Message = ",
        "I weigh nothing, but you can still see me.",
        "If you put me in a bucket, I make the bucket lighter.",
        "What am I?",
        "Answer = A hole",
        "Message = ",
        "What’s the difference between",
        "a hippo and a Zippo?",
        "Answer = ",
        "A hippo is really heavy, ",
        "and a Zippo is a little lighter."
    };

    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, fileLines);
}

private static void Main()
{
    // Set this to a file that doesn't exist or that you don't care about
    var filePath = @"f:\private\temp\temp.txt";

    // Create a file with multi-line messages
    CreateFile(filePath);

    // Read all the file text
    var fileText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    // Split it into the message/answers
    var messageAnswers = fileText.Split(new[] {"Message ="}, 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // Split each message into a message/answer array
    foreach (var messageAnswer in messageAnswers)
    {
        var parts = messageAnswer.Split(new[] {"Answer ="}, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var message = parts[0].Trim();
        var answer = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1].Trim() : "";

        Console.WriteLine(message);
        var userResponse = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

        if (userResponse.Equals(answer, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The actual answer is: " + answer);
        }
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```